# Why are my Texts not showing proper padding at start to align with the last Text content in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have three Texts contents as shown in the image [The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f50mg.png)

So, as you can the "Welcome" text is in middle but I want it at start , I have even given padding as start =17.dp but still it get's displayed in center, the middle text also isn't exactly aligned to the text content below it. I need every Line to be aligned properly at left side with leaving some padding start
Below is the code for my composable

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.aspectRatio
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.ButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.mayoclinic.ecg_frontend_android.constants.Destinations


@Composable
fun OnBoardingScreen1(navController: NavController) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 60.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    ) {
        // Image at the top-left corner
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(
                id = com.mayoclinic.ecg_frontend_android.R.drawable.purple
            ),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .aspectRatio(1.77f)
                .padding(top = 16.dp),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start, // Align the text to the left
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 17.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Welcome",
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp).wrapContentHeight()
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 15.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Mayo Clinic’s Research App",
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 24.sp,
                    lineHeight = 32.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                    color = Color(0xFF000000)
                )
            )
        }

        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 17.dp)
                .width(350.dp)
                .height(180.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Here you can join studies led by Mayo Clinic experts seeking to develop new and improved diagnostic tools, medications, devices, treatment protocols \n" +
                        "and more.",
                        style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 20.sp,
                lineHeight = 28.sp,
                fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                color = Color(0xFF000000)
            ),
                modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight()
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(100.dp))

        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(0.dp,
                Alignment.CenterVertically),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
        ) {
            // Button centered at the bottom
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(Destinations.OnBoardingScreen2)
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(top = 10.dp, bottom = 40.dp)
                    .height(50.dp),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(percent = 50),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xFF0057B8))
            ) {
                Text(text = "Next", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    style = TextStyle(Color.White))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put the "Welcome" and "Mayo Clinic’s Research App" inside the first `Column`, which has `CenterHorizontally` as alignment. All you need to do is put your closing curly bracket at the end of the first Column, like this:

```
 Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 60.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    ) {
        // Image at the top-left corner
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(
                id = com.mayoclinic.ecg_frontend_android.R.drawable.purple
            ),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .aspectRatio(1.77f)
                .padding(top = 16.dp),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
} // <-- HERE
```

Comment: Nope , it's not coming, it started showing entirely diffrent UI where button is above the image and no padding start for any Text. Can you provide entire code so i can just see where I am doing wrong?

Comment: You just need to wrap your columns into one big column so they show one after the other.